# angularjs:-control text box with user input values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

I am trying to create a text box wherein the user will send in the parameters and I have to display the text box on the page..

I will be having a text box where a user can submit the value eg:padding or text color and I have to display the text accordingly on an image displayed

The below code is to display the image which we get and to show the text on it :-

```
  <fieldset class="ng-binding">
            <legend>Upload on form submit</legend>
            Username:
            <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="username" size="39" required="">
            <i ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">*required</i>
            <br> Profile Picture:
            <input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="picFile" name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'" required="">
            <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
            <br> Profile Picture1:
            <input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="picFile1" name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'" required="">
            <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
            <br>

            <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit for pic one</button>
            <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="uploadPic(picFile1)">Submit for pic two</button>
            <img ngf-src="picFile" class="col-md-12 col-xs-6 thumb img img-responsive" style="position:relative">
            <div ng-if="picFile" class="internal" style ="margin:250px 0 0 250px;position:absolute">this is the internal working for file</div>
              <img ngf-src="picFile1" class="col-md-12 col-xs-6 thumb img img-responsive">
              <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
                    <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'" class="ng-binding"></div>
                </span>
              <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
          </fieldset>
```

I tried to control with the help of ng-model but not helping so far..Please help..

Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand properly what you want please be specific and precise.

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat There is an image i am getting..I want to put a text box on it based on the attributes given by a user on it..so I have a text box and give it a value margin:20px it should consider the value and the box should take the value

Comment: where is the code for the text box attributes?

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat I am not sure how to implement it and hence I am getting stuck

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for it?

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat https://plnkr.co/edit/Lm7cqEigLA4Gk7jGJhly?p=preview
I want to control the position of text box which is trigerred